# Cannot install .sh file

Tags: .sh

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to install a program. The "readme.txt" file says:

> to run program, write correct paths in the "program.sh" file (path to
>   the library ".../program/lib/" and to the executable file
>   ".../program/program").

and when I run `program.sh` it says:

```
#!/bin/sh
KYLIX_BIN="/home/$USER/program/program/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$KYLIX_BIN
/home/$USER/program/program/program $1
```

...where the string `program` is the name of the program I want to install.

Could you please help me to install the program?

Comment: what is the application (I am not sure I get the cryptic description of:  the program represents the name of program I want to install ;) ) could you provide a download link?

Comment: Are you doing this from the command line in a terminal? If so, are you launching the "program" with this: `$ ./program.sh` (where "`$`" represents prompt in terminal, of course).

Comment: You are new to Ubuntu and already installing programs not in the repository?
Are you sure what you're trying to install is not in the Software Centre?

Comment: I am afraid we have to be able to look into the files, the readme and the overall idea, to be able to help you. I am not quite getting the picture as it is now.

Comment: @Davïd I tried ./program.sh before, it doesn't work!

Comment: I have to look a bit closer ;) windows version runs right away (under wine), but linux version keeps with errors, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for.

I actually assumed this would be easy to solve. I tried to get it working under Linux; I definitely entered the right paths, but although the application (indeed) does not complain about paths (running it from the terminal), I could not get it working under Linux. Looking at posts on the internet on the subject, I found others with the same problem, but no confirmed solution.

Another thing is that the makers seem not to be very fond of their own Linux version:

```
"Note that the Linux version of Chemcraft has some significant
disadvantages. We were unable to make it as efficient as the Windows
version."
```

**A solution**

Altogether, I would suggest WINE, like the makers of ChemCraft suggest to MAC users.

```
"If you work under Mac and want to use Chemcraft, you can install Wine."
```

Wine is a compatibility layer for Linux (also for MAC) you can find WINE in the Software Center.

The good news is that I downloaded it to run under WINE, and it started straight away, it ran fine without any problem as far as I can see.

Comment: It should be easy! Software Center is one thing, but I always like to have Synaptic too (it is in... the Software Center ;)). Any way, if you give either SC or Synaptic the task to install Wine, it should be fine. Really, after a while, you will find out working with Linux is quite "clean", and once you get used to it, it is easy to control.

Comment: :)) it's not easy to work but I enjoy working with;) Thank a lot jacob for spending time and helping alot:) I will use wine then;)